# Formulário de contato em site intitucional

Tags: html

Qual a melhor forma de inserir um formulário funcional com entrada de texto, seleção múltipla escolha etc em um site estático (não pretendo usar php).

Sei como funciona o processo de construção e de envio, o que realmente gostaria de saber é se tem alguma solução que não utilize linguagem de prog

Comment: Não tem como fazer o envio de um formulário sem utilizar nenhuma linguagem *backend*.

Comment: Resposta: não! Você não pode fazer isso. Obviamente isso não seria seguro, porque você teria que expor seu servidor de email na internet, com a autenticação e tudo. Então, use uma linguagem de programação para enviar email.

Comment: Não sei se da certo Pq nunca tentei, mas as vezes vc pode conseguir um sistema de envio de terceiros, tipo um serviço de envio que vc vai usar no seu site como um iframe com o form de um outro site ou serviço de envio

Comment: Se você não quer colocar a mão nos códigos, recomendo utilizar Wordpress... Pelo menos você pode fazer algo mais "poderoso" como enviar emails e muito mais, sem precisar programar.

Answer (score 0):

É um pouco equivocado dizer que é impossível enviar um formulário sem um backend... Apenas não é prático e depende de recursos na máquina do usuário, como um cliente de e-mail configurado.

O exmplo abaixo é apenas uma demonstração disso e é uma péssima prática. Não seria muito diferente do que disponibilizar um link para o e-mail, o que de fato seria o mais recomendado se você não quer ter um backend.

```html
<form method="GET" action="mailto:email@dominio.com.br">
    <b>Assunto:</b>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="subject" />
    <br/>
    <b>Mensagem:</b>
    <br/>
    <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Neste caso, o envio não é feito pelo Front-End, mas sim por um programa de terceiros. Acho que não se enquadra.

Comment: @LeandroCastro, se enquadra... essa é a única maneira de você submeter um formulário e enviar um e-mail exclusivamente no frontend (apenas com recursos disponíveis no lado do cliente). Apesar de ser uma prática que já foi muito utilizada no passado, é uma péssima solução e não deve ser aplicada.

Comment: O que poderia ser feito, é a integração com alguma Web API para o envio... mas isso não é resolver apenas no front e sim utilizar o serviço de backend de algum terceiro